# Rubik Light Font is rendered instead of just Rubik

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to include [Rubik Font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik) in my project:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500; // or 400, or any, whatever
}
```

Here's also a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vrsjk4?file=index.html,styles.css,script.js) of this solution.

However, the computed font I see in Chrome Devtools is `Rubik Light`, no matter what font weight I set. I also tried to download it to use locally with no success.

How can I set `Rubik` font? `Rubik Light` looks kinda weird when bold.

I also cannot understand whether it's the problem with the font itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to select font styles via Google Fonts UI to get the following url:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
```

It's still `Rubik Light`, but now styles apply correctly.